# How to get total number of products in virtuemart?

Tags: sql, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I want to **display total number of products sold for each product**. There are around 30 products in my virtue mart and I want each one's total sold number.

Table named jos_vm_order_item contains product_id and product_quantity with all other information.

How can I display this?

Comment: How did you 'display total number of products sold for each product' on virtuemart? the answer above given by Mark is not clear to me.
Which file do I have to change and what changes do I have to make. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advanced. greeting from holland. daica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT O.product_id,
       SUM(O.product_quantity) as Total_Sold
  FROM jos_vm_order_item O
 GROUP BY O.product_id
```

Comment: I'm not a joomla expert. If you're retrieving the row data as an associative array, then it should be in $row['Total_Sold']